# error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token

Tags: c++, g++

I know there are a couple of similar questions(circular include) out stackoverflow and other websites. But I still can't figure it out and no solutions pop out. So I would like to post my specific one.

I have a Event class who has 2 and actually more subclass, which are Arrival and Landing. The compiler(g++) complains:

```
g++ -c -Wall -g -DDEBUG Event.cpp -o Event.o
In file included from Event.h:15,
                 from Event.cpp:8:
Landing.h:13: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
make: *** [Event.o] Error 1
```

People said that it's a circular include. The 3 header files(Event.h Arrival.h Landing.h) are as follows:

the Event.h:

```
#ifndef EVENT_H_
#define EVENT_H_

#include "common.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include "Flight.h"

#include "Landing.h"

class Arrival;

class Event : public Item {
public:
    Event(Flight* flight, int time);
    virtual ~Event();

    virtual void occur() = 0;
    virtual string extraInfo() = 0; // extra info for each concrete event

    // @implement
    int compareTo(Comparable* b);
    void print();

protected:
    /************** this is why I wanna include Landing.h *******************/
    Landing* createNewLanding(Arrival* arrival); // return a Landing obj based on arrival's info

private:
    Flight* flight;
    int time; // when this event occurs

};

#endif /* EVENT_H_ */
```

Arrival.h:

```
#ifndef ARRIVAL_H_
#define ARRIVAL_H_

#include "Event.h"

class Arrival: public Event {
public:
    Arrival(Flight* flight, int time);
    virtual ~Arrival();

    void occur();
    string extraInfo();
};

#endif /* ARRIVAL_H_ */
```

Landing.h

```
#ifndef LANDING_H_
#define LANDING_H_

#include "Event.h"

class Landing: public Event {/************** g++ complains here ****************/
public:
    static const int PERMISSION_TIME;

    Landing(Flight* flight, int time);
    virtual ~Landing();

    void occur();
    string extraInfo();
};

#endif /* LANDING_H_ */
```

UPDATE:

I included Landing.h due to Landing's constructor is called in the Event::createNewLanding method:

```
Landing* Event::createNewLanding(Arrival* arrival) {
    return new Landing(flight, time + Landing::PERMISSION_TIME);
}
```

Comment: According to the compiler output, your error is in `Landing.h` (on line 13).  Why did you put a comment in `Event.h` saying the error was there?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/625799/103167

Comment: Usually happens when the interface header is not included in child class.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Replace

```
#include "Landing.h"
```

with

```
class Landing;
```

If you still get errors, also post `Item.h`, `Flight.h` and `common.h`

EDIT: In response to comment.

You will need to e.g. `#include "Landing.h"` from `Event.cpp` in order to actually use the class. You just cannot include it from `Event.h`

Comment: because I called Landing's constructor:     Landing* Event::createNewLanding(Arrival* arrival) { return new Landing(flight, time + Landing::PERMISSION_TIME); }

Comment: `#include` the needed header files *in your .cpp* not your .h

Comment: that works. Thank you so much. Another question: does that implies that it's a good practice to always make foreword reference in you header file?

Comment: @draw: It's good practice to forward declare when forward declaration is enough (you only need `Type *` or `Type &`)- in addition to avoiding such circular include problems, this reduces interdependencies in between files, which a.o. reduces compile time.

Comment: Listen to the comment! Put `#include` in your .cpp, not your .h! That's what fixed it for me. You still need to ensure that your .h files are `#include`d so that ones that are defined by others are lower down. Also, as stated in previous comments, you can use forward declarations of classes to help when anything is circularly defined.

Comment: Add one possible cause if already have the .h file but class name still not recognized: check if there are multiple files with same name.

Answer (score 101):

This should be a comment, but comments don't allow multi-line code.

Here's what's happening:

in `Event.cpp`

```
#include "Event.h"
```

preprocessor starts processing `Event.h`

```
#ifndef EVENT_H_
```

it isn't defined yet, so keep going

```
#define EVENT_H_
#include "common.h"
```

`common.h` gets processed ok

```
#include "Item.h"
```

`Item.h` gets processed ok

```
#include "Flight.h"
```

`Flight.h` gets processed ok

```
#include "Landing.h"
```

preprocessor starts processing `Landing.h`

```
#ifndef LANDING_H_
```

not defined yet, keep going

```
#define LANDING_H_

#include "Event.h"
```

preprocessor starts processing `Event.h`

```
#ifndef EVENT_H_
```

This IS defined already, the whole rest of the file gets skipped.  Continuing with `Landing.h`

```
class Landing: public Event {
```

The preprocessor doesn't care about this, but the compiler goes "WTH is `Event`?  I haven't heard about `Event` yet."

Comment: @Ben           If we use `class Landing` instead of `#include "Landing.h"`, will `Landing` be defined twice? If the preprocessor does not skip `#ifndef LANDING_H_`, how it treats `class Landing`? As defined or not?

Comment: @MiloLu: That's why you use a forward declaration `class Landing;` which is not a definition (no body in `{}`).

Answer (score 4):

If you forward-declare `Flight` and `Landing` in `Event.h`, then you should be fixed.

Remember to `#include "Flight.h"` and `#include "Landing.h"` in your implementation file for `Event`.

The general rule of thumb is:  if you derive from it, or compose from it, or use it by value, the compiler must know its full definition at the time of declaration.  If you compose from a pointer-to-it, the compiler will know how big a pointer is.  Similarly, if you pass a reference to it, the compiler will know how big the reference is, too.

Comment: `#include <privateheader.h>` is generally incorrect - Use `"privateheader.h"`

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error with a different problem,

I used namespaces in my headers and forgot the closing bracket and got this cryptic error instead.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a bit late to answer this question, but it is the first entry in google, so I think it is worth to answer it.

The problem is not a coding problem, it is an architecture problem.

You have created an interface `class Event: public Item` to define the methods which all events should implement. Then you have defined two types of events which inherits from `class Event: public Item`; Arrival and Landing and then, you have added a method `Landing* createNewLanding(Arrival* arrival);` from the landing functionality in the `class Event: public Item` interface. You should move this method to the `class Landing: public Event` class because it only has sense for a landing. `class Landing: public Event` and `class Arrival: public Event` class should know `class Event: public Item` but event should not know `class Landing: public Event` nor `class Arrival: public Event`.

I hope this helps, regards, Alberto