# error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Item’

Tags: c++

I have been having a lot of trouble with my headers and making sure everything is declared correctly. First off my files:

```
//Main.cpp
#include "Item.h"
#include "Warehouse.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ...
}

//Item.h
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Item {
    ...
};
#endif  /* ITEM_H */

//Item.cpp
#include "Item.h"

//Warehouse.h
#define WAREHOUSE_H
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H
using namespace std;

class Item;
class Warehouse {
    ...
private:
    Item* array; //problem starts with this
};
#endif  /* WAREHOUSE_H */

//Warehouse.cpp
#include "Warehouse.h"
#include "Item.h"

Warehouse::Warehouse() {
    array = new Item[arraySize]; //and this is where I get the error
}
```

I am pretty sure the problem has to do with my header in Warehouse.h but every combination I try does not work. Sorry if not enough of the code is posted but I figure the problem is with the includes and declarations.

Thanks ahead of time.

edit: to clarify this is not in one file. I just wrote it like this to simplify things. Each one of the above is a separate file.

Comment: Your include guards are all messed up.

Comment: You're missing semicolons at the end of all your classes. Also, it's *really really* not a good idea to put `using namespace` inside a header.

Comment: `main()` last is usually a good idea

Comment: Think of what happens when two different header files have the same include guards.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I feel like this question would benefit from an answer in [this style](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5320021/103167)  Feel free to cut+paste if that saves you time.

Answer (score 3):

Your include guards in the header file `Warehouse.h` are not correct.

Instead of

```
//Warehouse.h
#define WAREHOUSE_H
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H
using namespace std;

// ...

#endif  /* WAREHOUSE_H */
```

you want

```
//Warehouse.h
#ifndef WAREHOUSE_H
#define WAREHOUSE_H
using namespace std;

// ...

#endif  /* WAREHOUSE_H */
```

With the current version the class definition in `item.h` is never included in `Warehouse.cpp` because the mixed-up include guards in `Warehouse.h` prevent `item.h` to be read due to the order of

```
//Warehouse.cpp
#include "Warehouse.h"
#include "Item.h"    //Warehouse.cpp
#include "Warehouse.h"
#include "Item.h"
```

Then the compiler does not know the definition of `Item` at that point, hence the error.

Another thing: Do not form the habit of `using namespace std` in header files. This will lead to issues at some point.

Comment: Aside: `using namespace std;` is not cool, especially in header files.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in this declaration

```
private:
    Item* array; //problem starts with this
```

You may define a pointer to an incomplete type.

I think the problem is in a statement where you try to allocate an object for this pointer using operator new or to dereference the pointer.

Also I do not see any reason why you do not want to include header Item.h in header Warehouse.h instead of using elaborated name

```
class Item;
```