# Expected class-name before { token SDL error

Tags: c++, sdl

I get this error i have a class Enemy and a class Player and a Class SDLGameObject

Error:
`expected class-name before '{' token` It's on line 15 at location `Enemy : public SDLGameObject {`

class Enemy

```
/*
 * Enemy.h
 *
 *  Created on: 15 apr. 2014
 *      Author: JAN
 */

#ifndef ENEMY_H_
#define ENEMY_H_

#include "SDLGameObject.h"

class Enemy : public SDLGameObject {
public:
    Enemy(const LoaderParams* pParams);

     virtual void draw();
     virtual void update();
     virtual void clean();
};

#endif /* ENEMY_H_ */
```

class Player

```
/*
 * Player.h
 *
 *  Created on: 15 apr. 2014
 *      Author: JAN
 */

#ifndef PLAYER_H_
#define PLAYER_H_


#include "SDLGameObject.h"

class Player : public SDLGameObject {
public:
     Player(const LoaderParams* pParams);

     virtual void draw();
     virtual void update();
     virtual void clean();

};

#endif /* PLAYER_H_ */
```

class SDLGameObject

```
/*
 * SDLGameObject.h
 *
 *  Created on: 15 apr. 2014
 *      Author: JAN
 */

#ifndef SDLGAMEOBJECT_H_
#define SDLGAMEOBJECT_H_

#include "GameObject.h"
#include "TextureManager.h"
#include "Game.h"

class SDLGameObject : public GameObject {
public:
     SDLGameObject(const LoaderParams* pParams);
     virtual void draw();
     virtual void update();
     virtual void clean();

protected:
     int m_x;
     int m_y;

     int m_width;
     int m_height;

     int m_currentRow;
     int m_currentFrame;

     std::string m_textureID;

};

#endif /* SDLGAMEOBJECT_H_ */
```

i also have an abstract class GameObject

```
/*
 * GameObject.h
 *
 *  Created on: 15 apr. 2014
 *      Author: JAN
 */

#ifndef GAMEOBJECT_H_
#define GAMEOBJECT_H_

#include "LoaderParams.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class GameObject {
public:

    virtual void draw() = 0;
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual void clean() = 0;


protected:

     GameObject(const LoaderParams* pParams) {}
     virtual ~GameObject() {}
};

#endif /* GAMEOBJECT_H_ */
```

a Class LoaderParams to load teh parameters of the different objects

```
/*
 * LoaderParams.h
 *
 *  Created on: 15 apr. 2014
 *      Author: JAN
 */

#ifndef LOADERPARAMS_H_
#define LOADERPARAMS_H_



#include <string>
using namespace std;

class LoaderParams {
public:

     LoaderParams(int x, int y, int width, int height, std::string   textureID) : m_x(x), m_y(y), m_width(width), m_height(height),   m_textureID(textureID)
    {

    }

     int getX() const { return m_x; }
     int getY() const { return m_y; }
     int getWidth() const { return m_width; }
     int getHeight() const { return m_height; }
     std::string getTextureID() const { return m_textureID; }

private:

     int m_x;
     int m_y;
     int m_width;
     int m_height;
     std::string m_textureID;

};

#endif /* LOADERPARAMS_H_ */
```

also a class Game

```
* Game.h
 *
 *  Created on: 15 apr. 2014
 *      Author: JAN
 */

#ifndef GAME_H_
#define GAME_H_

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <vector>
#include "TextureManager.h"
#include "Gameobject.h"
#include "SDLGameobject.h"





class Game {
public:

    static Game* Instance()
    {
        if(s_pInstance == 0)
        {
            s_pInstance = new Game();
            return s_pInstance;
        }
        return s_pInstance;
    }

    //simply set the running variable to true
    bool init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, int flags);
    void render();
    void update();
    void handleEvents();
    void clean();

    SDL_Renderer* getRenderer() const { return m_pRenderer; }




    std::vector<GameObject*> m_gameObjects;


    //a function to access private running variable

    bool running() {return m_bRunning; }

private:

     Game(); // create the s_pInstance member variable
     static Game* s_pInstance;


    SDL_Window* m_pWindow;
    SDL_Renderer* m_pRenderer;

    int m_currentFrame;
    bool m_bRunning;
};
typedef Game TheGame;
#endif /* GAME_H_ */
```

and finally a class TextureManager

```
/*
 * TextureManager.h
 *
 *  Created on: 15 apr. 2014
 *      Author: JAN
 */

#ifndef TEXTUREMANAGER_H_
#define TEXTUREMANAGER_H_

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;



class TextureManager {
public:

    static TextureManager* Instance()
     {
        if(s_pInstance == 0)
        {
            s_pInstance = new TextureManager();
            return s_pInstance;
        }
        return s_pInstance;
    }

    bool load(std::string fileName,std::string id,  SDL_Renderer* pRenderer);

    void draw(std::string id, int x, int y, int width, int  height, SDL_Renderer* pRenderer, SDL_RendererFlip flip =  SDL_FLIP_NONE);

    void drawFrame(std::string id, int x, int y, int width, int  height, int currentRow, int currentFrame, SDL_Renderer*  pRenderer, SDL_RendererFlip flip = SDL_FLIP_NONE);

    std::map<std::string, SDL_Texture*> m_textureMap;



private:
    TextureManager() {}
    TextureManager(const TextureManager&);
      TextureManager& operator=(const TextureManager&);

      static TextureManager* s_pInstance;


};


typedef TextureManager TheTextureManager;
#endif /* TEXTUREMANAGER_H_ */
```

where am i placing my includes wrong? I don't seem to figure this out. Sometimes the error dissapears by Player and appears by enemy and the way around.

In `Class game.cpp`

Error:

```
m_gameObjects.push_back(new Player(new LoaderParams(100, 100, 128, 82, "animate")));
m_gameObjects.push_back(new Enemy(new LoaderParams(300, 300, 128, 82, "animate")));
```

now i get expected type-specifier before 'Enemy' error

In game.h

```
s_pInstance = new Game();
```

Error undefined reference to `Game::Game()'

Comment: Specify the exact error message in your question. Like it is it's useless (although you posted the code).

Comment: Are you sure that `SDLGameObject` is declared in the global namespace?

Comment: You can have this error when header files include each other(circularly). Are you doing this in any of your other headers? Could be that somewhere along the line (possibly in `Game.h`) the `Enemy.h` header included and thus included in `SDLGameObject.h`

Comment: yes i think im doing this ! but i can't find out which one it is

Comment: @user3531442 If you are, then a simple solution is replace `#include "SDLGameObject.h"` with `class SDPGameObject` in the `Enemy.h`. See [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319906/error-expected-class-name-before-token)

Comment: no that doesn't work should i post my fully code?

Comment: i updated my fully code with all the headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Game.h` and `SDLGameObject.h` include each other. So, to correct that, replace `#include "SDLGameObject.h"` with `class SDLGameObject` in your `Game.h` file.

If you are calling the class in `Game.cpp` include your `SDLGameObject.h` header there instead of in `Game.h` because you will not have access to it any other way. Also, for good measure, move the inclusion of `Game.h` to your `SDLGameObject.cpp` definition file.

EDIT: You may also want to include `Enemy.h` in your `Game.cpp` file. This would be true for any class that your program states you don't have that type specified after your header include switches.

Comment: oke now i get another error i just edited the post so you can look

Comment: @user3531442 please see my edit. Also may be how you implement the Enemy class, not sure on that one.

Comment: thanks but again there's one more error i will edited allready thank you very much for your help i think this is the last one!

Comment: @user3531442 that has nothing to do with headers or was caused by the answer I gave you. But, move your `private` section of the class above the `public` section. How can it call the constructor if it has not been declared yet?