# Visual Studio doesn't include header

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Here is my BoardField.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "ChessPiece.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <SDL.h>

class BoardField{
private:
    ChessPiece m_piece;
    SDL_Rect m_field;

public:

    friend class Game;
};
```

And Game.h

```
#pragma once

#include "BoardField.h"

class Game {
private:
    //members
    BoardField* m_board_fields; // 16th line
    ...

    //methods
    ...
public:
    ...
};
```

And I'm getting these errors in VS2017 when trying to compile :

[image: Error]

Where is the problem? Even tried to create new project it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: which line is line 16? I presume the second block of code is game.h? does the error occur if you compile just the code you posted?

Comment: `BoardField.h` includes `Game.h` which includes `BoardField.h`. `BoardField` depends on `Game` which depends on `BoardField` which depends on `Game` which... And so on forever. One of the classes will be used before it is declared. Do some research about *circular inclusion* and *circular dependencies* and *forward declarations*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how to avoid it and be able to make class a friend?

Comment: @FaustasButkus again, do some research on the items that were mentioned. Particularly "*forward declarations*"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319906/error-expected-class-name-before-token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To break the circular references, you should use a forward reference. Since you are using a raw pointer, that's all that is required:

```
#pragma once

class BoardField;

class Game {
private:
    //members
    BoardField* m_board_fields;
    ...

    //methods
    ...
public:
    ...
};
```

Of course, in [Modern C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279654.aspx) you should be avoiding raw pointers. For a case like a privately owned heap allocation, [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is the best option in most cases:

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

class BoardField;

class Game {
private:
    //members
    std::unique_ptr<BoardField> m_board_fields;
    ...

    //methods
    ...
public:
    ...
};
```

You should read [this blog post](http://gernotklingler.com/blog/care-include-dependencies-cpp-keep-minimum/)